# Cannot setup password change policy on Yosemite server

Tags: mac, opendirectory

We are running a Yosemite server 10.10.5 with Server.app 5.03.

I can setup network user and assign him a password, but regardless i set up policy to  change password on next login user logins without password change prompt.

I also can manually change user password leaving box "Require password change at next login" ticked but user just logins with new password assigned  still without a prompt.

I have a backup of OD where this feature worked correctly but even if i restore it it is not working any more.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tries to run `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow PasswordExpirationDays NUMBER` ?

it's from [the source](https://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-change-password-expiration-warning-intervals-in-os-x/) and works for me.

Comment: it looks like a command to be issued on local computer but i need a solution to run on OD server